# How can I make an ORM query that leverages MySQL late row lookups?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm, database-performance

In my django application I have defined a model like so:

```
class NamedContainer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    capacity_ml = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name', 'capacity_ml']
```

Over time, this table has grown big enough to start causing some query performance issues, **specifically when relying on limit/offset for slicing**. Other slicing methods may have better performance by design, but for now I'm stuck with limit/offset, unfortunately.

However, [MySQL has a technique called "late row lookups"](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/) which greatly helps with my problem and, in short, a raw MySQL query using this technique could look something like

```
SELECT t2.* FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `core_namedcontainer`
    WHERE `updated_at` >= '2019-01-01 05:00:00.000Z'
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 500 OFFSET 10000
) AS t1
JOIN `core_namedcontainer` AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY `name` ASC, `capacity_ml` ASC
```

I have only managed to mangle the ORM query to produce a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM `core_namedcontainer`
WHERE (
  `core_namedcontainer`.`id` IN (
      SELECT U0.`id`
      FROM `core_namedcontainer` U0
      WHERE (
        U0.`updated_at` >= 2019-01-01 05:00:00
      )
      ORDER BY U0.`name` ASC, U0.`capacity_ml` ASC
      LIMIT 500 OFFSET 10000
    )
)
ORDER BY `core_namedcontainer`.`name` ASC, `core_namedcontainer`.`capacity_mL` ASC
```

which simply uses a subquery instead of a join to itself, and when evaluating the query, MySQL complains with

```
NotSupportedError: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")
```

**The django app is using MySQL 5.6 and, for a variety of reasons, it will take quite a while before it can upgrade to anything newer.**

I'm aware I could just issue the raw SQL query the way I need it, but I am hoping there is a way to translate this technique to Django ORM syntax so that I could leverage this technique on my model as the base queryset:

```
class NamedContainerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        # do some ORM magic here to implement mysql late row lookup in all queries
        return queryset

class NamedContainer(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = NamedContainerManager()
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`OFFSET` can lead to skipping or duplicating rows.  Beware.

`OFFSET` is O(N*N).  This is because it must step over all the 'offset' rows.

A better solution is to 'remember where you left off' instead of using `OFFSET`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

You say "now I'm stuck with limit/offset".  I don't accept that.  Reformulating to remember where you left off should be possible in the ORM.

Comment: hey, thanks so much for the answer!! but unfortunately this needs to be worked around with limit/offset as bad as it sounds :(I know there are quite better pagination algorithms, even as simple cursor-based pagination. "I don't accept that", neither would I want to but I have to, unfortunately I don't make the rules in this project 

Comment: My blog was based on work done in MySQL 4.1, long before 5.6.  Perhaps your Boss should read this Q&A, plus my blog?